# Uploading Web Files Directly To Drive Using Url in python Api

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, file-upload, google-drive-api

I'm using the python client library of Drive REST v3 . I am able to upload any files that are on my local machine to drive, but I'm unable to find how to upload files on the web to google drive using their download links without saving them to my machine first. I've seen this functionality in web-based applications, but I can't find how to implement the same thing in Installed Applications.

Web Implementations :

https://save.thoaimedia.com/

https://savetodrive.net

Comment: how do you know https://save.thoaimedia.com/ is not saving it local and uploading it ?

Comment: Because I'm able to view the data transfer speed on savetodrive. If they were saving it locally then the transfer speed should be near about same for all  
Files, but it's notm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no mention on how to upload on Google Drive using the Blob or link on the [Upload guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads) but you can try the workaround in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47833728/url-to-upload-to-google-drive).

Comment: So there's no other option than Web Apps? Thanks. I just wanted to know if the same functionality could be implemented in python API.